# Call Web API in Ionic 3

Tags: asp.net-web-api, cors, ionic3

I have created simple API in MVC.

I want to call it from Ionic App. I wrote code in my `WebApiConfig.cs` file to allow CORS. But when I try to call same from Ionic it throws an error:

> Failed to load http://localhost:53377/api/member/2: No
>   'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource. Origin 'http://localhost:8100' is therefore not allowed
>   access.

How can I resolve the issue?

Answer (score 0):

In each applications when you are going to send requests to another web application, you must set the Access-Control-Allow-Origin header.

This post has complete info about it.

[Access-Control-Allow-Origin header](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10636611/how-does-access-control-allow-origin-header-work)

Answer (score 0):

My English is not good, but I will try to help you.

Add this in your web.config

```
  <httpProtocol>
   <customHeaders>
    <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
    <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="Content-Type" />
    <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" value="GET" />
  </customHeaders>
</httpProtocol>
```

See your requisitions allowed in Access-Control-Allow-Methods. Add GET, POST, PUT OR DELETE according to your need.

**Alert**: I don't know of informations of security about it. But in simple requisition, should solve.

**Alert 2**: I reccomend to pass a security token in webapi requisition.